# Any strategies for dealing with superseded and depreciated functions in R (tidyverse)?

Tags: r, tidyverse, r-package

Is there a utility/function/package to check to see if an R script is using any superseded or depreciated functions?

I ask because I just noticed that one of my packages uses `dplyr::mutate_all()` which I know is superseded by `across()`.  I checked my package's files for "mutate_" and rewrote those function calls.  So that batch of depreciated functions are fixed but I don't know how to check for *all* superseded and/or depreciated functions.

Does anybody have a strategy for dealing with this issue?

Answer (score 5):

There is `lifecycle` package which can show the superseded/deprecated functions

```
library(lifecycle)
pkg_lifecycle_statuses("dplyr")
```

-output

```
  package                fun    lifecycle
4     dplyr       add_rownames   deprecated
5     dplyr          all_equal  questioning
6     dplyr           all_vars   superseded
7     dplyr           any_vars   superseded
10    dplyr        arrange_all   superseded
11    dplyr         arrange_at   superseded
12    dplyr         arrange_if   superseded
...
```

Comment: That helps a bunch.  Has anybody built function (or better yet an RStudio addin) to check for these functions in a script?

Comment: @itsMeInMiami you can wrap some of the functions in `lifecycle` for warning deprecated/superseded functions i.e. there is `deprecated` function in `lifecycle`

Comment: I am not aware of Rstudio addin